# Spring Boot Scheduled Task Not Running

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, javabeans, quartz-scheduler

I cannot figure out why my scheduled task will not run. Most of the help I've read out there says they're missing @EnableScheduling on entry class or they're missing @Component on the component which the scheduler is on. I have both of these present in my code so I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

**UPDATE:**
I see that if I comment out the taskExecutor bean it starts to work. How can I maintain my task executor and use the Scheduler?

**Main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class MonitoringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MonitoringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-thread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Configuration
    public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
        }
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class HealthMonitor {

    ArrayList<Application> apps = new ArrayList<>();

    HashMap<String, String> groupQuery = new HashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    MyMonitoringAdapter monitoringAdapter;

    @Autowired
    ServiceNowAdapter snowAdapter;

    @Autowired
    SitePinger sitePinger;

    @PostConstruct
    public void getAllAppHealth() {
        System.out.println("Monitor starting up...");
        buildAllApplications();
        populateProductLine();
        populateAppMonitors();
        getIncidents();
        System.out.println("Monitor started! - async processes may still be running");
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void scheduledRefresh() {
        System.out.println("Fixed rate task async - ");
        refreshPing();
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your own edit remove the `TaskExecutor` and let Spring Boot configure that (you can configure it in `application.properties`). Also are you sure you want 100 threads and that maximum (it will probably become a bottleneck somewhere).

Comment: Would the recommended solution be to just let spring handle it? I was reading a guide on setting up async in springboot and they had the best performance with something similiar

Comment: I did the same but I am not facing any issue. It is clearly working for me. Only change is I don't have `WebConfiguration` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: In versions prior to Spring Boot 2.1 there was no pre-configured `TaskExecutor` as of Spring Boot 2.1 there is which you can easily configure through properties. The drawback of guides using older versions, so you don't need `TaskExecutor`. Also scheduling uses a `TaskScheduler` not a `TaskExecutor`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and help understanding that @M.Deinum . How would I close this question as resolved?